# Trying to access parent function in child component using ref

Tags: react-native

I have the following snack:

```
https://snack.expo.io/@drc83/ref-close-modal
```

I would like to access the function from the parent. I have tried to pass the function via ref. When you click close modal (in the child component), this should call the function closeModalView in the parent component and trigger the alert('Close Modal'). Currently when pressed I get undefined error, any help resolving would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need refs to do this, just modified your code and this works, It will show an alert and if you click ok It will close the modal

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import StepOne from './components/StepOne';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalVisible: false,
    };
     this.modalView = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.onRef) {
      this.props.onRef(this);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.props.onRef) {
      this.props.onRef(undefined);
    }
  }

  closeModalView = () => {
    Alert.alert(
  'Close Modal',
  'This will close the Modal',
  [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
  };

  showModalView = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: true });
//alert('true');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingTop: 200 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}
          onPress={() => this.showModalView()}>
          <Text>OPEN MODAL</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
          style={{
            bottom: 0,
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}
          onModalHide={this.closeModalView}
          onBackButtonPress={this.closeModal}
          backdropOpacity={0.5}>
          <StepOne closeModal={()=> this.closeModalView()} />
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was told to use refs when passing functions but not been told why. Are there any performance issues between these techniques? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure who told you that, but even in [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) they say not to over use refs

Answer (score 0):

In App.js (where closeModal is passed as a prop to StepOne) replace

closeModal={()=> this.modalView.closeModalView()}

with

closeModal={this.closeModalView}

This should work.

The function closeModalView is not defined on this.modalView. Hence the child is not getting the function.